# Modifying PDF (compatible with Acrobat 6.0 and higher) by objects shuffling

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to get PDF file, with changed order of objects (index is not changed, only location of objects inside file).
After then, I'm making new xref stream with new offsets of objects

I implemented the program in Python, but produced file is always damaged.

Questions:

1. How to make file unlinearized? Currently, I'm removing linearisation object from file and its xref-entry
2. Token "endstream" should be clearly separated from its content by \r\n, or it's not necessary?
3. ....

May be I missed some important facts and nuances? I will appreciate any help

Comment: Would you mind showing us a [mcve] ?

Comment: Are you using an existing Python package for parsing and writing PDF files, or are you rolling your own?

Comment: I fixed several foolish bugs and currently shuffling works. But only with compressed non-linearized files.
However I still damaging linearized files, but I think there're some nuances about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you neither show your code nor describe the nature of the damage to the result file (let alone share sample original and reordered files), it is difficult to help you.

> 1. How to make file unlinearized? Currently, I'm removing linearisation object from file and its xref-entry

Removing the Linearization Parameter Dictionary is a good idea. Concerning the cross references be aware that the entries in both tables are relevant.

> 2. Token "endstream" should be clearly separated from its content by \r\n, or it's not necessary?

To quote the PDF specification:

> There should be an end-of-line marker after the data and before endstream
>
> *(section 7.3.8 Stream Objects - ISO 32000-1)*

"Should" indicates a strong recommendation but not a requirement. Thus, your code has to expect to be confronted with PDFs which don't have an end-of-line marker there.

By the way,

> The CARRIAGE RETURN (0Dh) and LINE FEED (0Ah) characters, also called newline characters, shall be
>   treated as end-of-line (EOL) markers. The combination of a CARRIAGE RETURN followed immediately by a
>   LINE FEED shall be treated as one EOL marker.
>
> *(section 7.2.2 Character Set - ISO 32000-1)*

Thus, even if there is an end-of-line marker, it is not necessarily `\r\n`, it might also be a single `\r` or `\n`.